# My printer is only printing in economy mode

Tags: cups, printing

I have a HP LaserJet Pro 404dn and I can't make it print in high quality. It seems it only prints in some economy mode. The letters are not fully filled . they are not sharp or properly filled.
I try to configure the printer to print in high quality. I have the HP-ljp packages installed.
In the systems setting -> the printer -> Printing Options -> Advanced
I can set quality to "Draft, Normal, High" but if I select "High" and then close the dialog (there is no "apply" or "save" button) the settings is gone when I open the dialog again and it is back to "normal". That is quite strange.

When I print a pdf using Okular I can only choose from "Economy" and "Normal" mode.
When I open the same pdf through firefox and choose "print with system dialog" I get some dialog where I can select High quality, and the print looks almost perfect.

I have no clue on how to solve this to get the proper high quality print. Printing through the webbrowser is not a very viable solution in the longterm.
I connect to the printer over the network with IPPS